# Run parallel tasks in Apache Airflow

Tags: airflow

I am able to configure `airflow.cfg` file to run tasks one after the other.

What I want to do is, execute tasks in parallel, e.g. 2 at a time and reach the end of list.

How can I configure this?

Answer (score 12):

Executing tasks in Airflow in parallel depends on which executor you're using, e.g., `SequentialExecutor`, `LocalExecutor`, `CeleryExecutor`, etc.

For a simple setup, you can achieve parallelism by just setting your executor to `LocalExecutor` in your airflow.cfg:

```
[core]
executor = LocalExecutor
```

Reference: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/29ae02a070132543ac92706d74d9a5dc676053d9/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L76

This will spin up a separate process for each task.

(Of course you'll need to have a DAG with at least 2 tasks that can execute in parallel to see it work.)

Alternatively, with `CeleryExecutor`, you can spin up any number of workers by just running (as many times as you want):

```
$ airflow worker
```

The tasks will go into a Celery queue and each Celery worker will pull off of the queue.

You might find the section *Scaling out with Celery* in the Airflow Configuration docs helpful.

https://airflow.apache.org/howto/executor/use-celery.html

For any executor, you may want to tweak the core settings that control parallelism once you have that running.

They're all found under `[core]`.  These are the defaults:

```
# The amount of parallelism as a setting to the executor. This defines
# the max number of task instances that should run simultaneously
# on this airflow installation
parallelism = 32

# The number of task instances allowed to run concurrently by the scheduler
dag_concurrency = 16

# Are DAGs paused by default at creation
dags_are_paused_at_creation = True

# When not using pools, tasks are run in the "default pool",
# whose size is guided by this config element
non_pooled_task_slot_count = 128

# The maximum number of active DAG runs per DAG
max_active_runs_per_dag = 16
```

Reference: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/29ae02a070132543ac92706d74d9a5dc676053d9/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L99

Comment: I tried going through the setup but now none of my DAGs ever start or get scheduled. I've created a post for it with details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50632598/running-airflow-tasks-in-parallel-nothing-gets-scheduled

Comment: Hey everyone you may need to do these steps afterwards to reset everything once you make the changes: First shut down the `webserver` and `scheduler` using `kill theirPIDs` or `ctrl + c` if it's open still in the terminal. Then delete all the entries under `/home/ec2-user/airflow/dags/__pycache__`. Then restart the postgre database using `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart` then run `airflow resetdb`. Then run `airflow webserver` and `airflow scheduler`. Go in the UI and turn on the DAG and voila it should work.

Comment: Also everyone this post provides more detail https://stlong0521.github.io/20161023%20-%20Airflow.html and I ran into some errors when setting up the postgre database and so this post helped me fixed the errors https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-install-PostgreSQL-on-AWS-EC2-and-how-can-I-access-that I followed the solution by Rajit Kapoor he gave super detailed instructions. I ran into one more tiny error and used this to fix it https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/31673/psqlexception-fatal-no-pg-hbaconf-entry-for-host-1.html